# Can you prevent innerHTML from removing HTML, HEAD, BODY elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a wysiwyg into an app, they all use `contentEditable` which is cool until i put an entire html document into a text box. Each wysiwyg uses `html()` and `innerHTML` to move the content around and both of these strip , , and  tags...

```
html = "<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span>Hey There</span>
  </body>
  </html>
  "

editable.innerHTML = html
editable.innerHTML
// => "
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <span>Hey There</span>
"
```

same exact thing happens with `$(editable).html()`. I cannot find spec regarding this.

what do?

Comment: And how the heck does codemirror and ace editor allow you to input entire html documents and not parse them out?

Comment: That's probably the browser, as you can only have one of those tags in the document. Not sure how other sites do it, but I'm guessing iFrame ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HTML document can only have a single `html`, `body` and `head` element, and your main page already has those. It is stripping it out because you are trying to insert them in positions that are not allowed.

You'd either have to strip those out entirely and then add them back on after the element content is edited, or put your entire WYSIWYG editor inside an `iframe` element so that you have the whole iframe document to work with rather than a single element.

It is documented, though you kind of need to know what you are looking for. See the [`<body>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) docs on MDN:

> Permitted parent elements: It must be the second element of an  element.

and from the docs for `<html>`:

> Permitted parent elements: As the root element of a document, or wherever a subdocument fragment is allowed in a compound document.

Comment: thank you, I thought 3 different WYSIWYGs were broken. Is this so incredibly well known that it would be a waste of time to document(mozilla/msdn/W3C) because i've been googling like a fool to figure this out :(

Comment: Updated to answer your question

Comment: Yeah i could not parse that. was looking more for your first sentence... Thank you!